# Erro de instância typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Olá, estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
{statusCode: 400,…}
error: "Bad Request"
message: ["last_transaction_date must be a Date instance", "date must be a Date instance"]
0: "last_transaction_date must be a Date instance"
1: "date must be a Date instance"
statusCode: 400
```

Vindo do seguinte código:

```
import { IsDate, IsEmail, IsOptional, IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class FilterWebhookCancelDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  client_name?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  code?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsDate()
  @IsString()
  last_transaction_date?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsDate()
  @IsString()
  date?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @IsEmail()
  client_email?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  last_transaction_status?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  value?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  client_cpf?: string;
}
```

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo aqui?

Comment: Está dando 2 erros nas propriedades **last_transaction_date** e **date**, segundo a mensagem de erro é pq essas propriedades deveriam ser tipadas como **`Date()`** só que vc as tipou como sendo **`string`**, já tentou utilizar um **type union**? Assim: `date: string | Date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está fazendo os tipos brigarem.

```
  @IsOptional()
  @IsDate()
  @IsString() <---- Se é um Date não pode ser String
  last_transaction_date?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsDate()
  @IsString()<---- Se é um Date não pode ser String
  date?: string;
```

Então ficaria assim:

```
  @IsOptional()
  @IsDate()
  last_transaction_date?: Date;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsDate()
  date?: Date;
```